# PhpStorm - how to find all wrong imports(use) in classes ? (PHP)

Tags: php, phpstorm

Look at my PHP code, my import is wrong but is there any feature in PhpStorm to find all wrong imports in all classes (codebase)?

I don't want to check each class one by one manually.

[image: wrong phpstorm imports(]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Code | Inspect Code...` .. or `Code | Run Inspection by Name...` if you know (or can guess) the exact inspection name. It can then be run on current file/folder or specific Scope.

In your case it most likely will be the `Undefined class` inspection.

---

`Code | Optimize Imports` may also be a little helpful here ... but:

- It will not report anything as it will modify the code straight away.
- It's more about removing definitely unused `use` statements (known classes but no longer/never used in this file) and rearranging their order: it will not tell what is wrong (i.e. it will not remove or report such `PostAddToCartwrong` line).

Comment: Also, the "Unused import" inspection can be useful to find all such imports in batch.

Comment: It's very annoying that you can't filter comments out of the inspection. I want to inspect only real code, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in Code menu for that. For example it arranges imports, as well as removes unused ones.
More detailed info here https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/03/optimize-imports-for-php/